# dojo dijit createLink question

Tags: forms, dojo

One question about Dojo Dijit's "createLink".

Clicking on a created link doesn't actually pop up and show the link's URL page, but clicking a link shows the link properties dialog again and again.

How do I make so that it show the link's URL on the page?

http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/_editor/plugins/LinkDialog?highlight=%28createlink%29"

In the document, it says "Double-Clicking on a link should activate the Link Properties dialog dropdown on the button.".

I want to create a "link" to a page!
Please help.

---

the sample code I tried is this.

```
<html><head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dojo/resources/dojo.css" type="text/css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css" type="text/css"> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> <!-- dojo.require("dijit.Editor"); dojo.require("dijit._editor.plugins.LinkDialog"); //--> </script> </head> <body class="soria"> <div dojoType="dijit.Editor" id="editor" extraPlugins="['createLink', 'unlink']"></div> </body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The link dialog is a function of the editor to insert hypertext.  The editor creates HTML, and this hyperlink will be constructed as an  tag.  You are in the editor and you can edit the content, but not actually use the hypertext until you take that content and populate it somewhere else, perhaps saving it on a server and loading it in another part of your application.

Comment: I see, the link dialog only creates HTML. So, to make it link to url's page, I have to load the html to somewhere else.
Thanks for your advice.